# How to get classification probabilities in Keras?

Tags: keras, classification, conv-neural-network, predict, softmax

I am trying to get classification probabilities out of my trained Keras model but when I use the model.predict (or model.predict_proba) method, all I get is an array of this form: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

So basically I get a one hot encoded float array. The "1" is mostly in the right place so the training seems to have worked fine. But why can't I get the probabilities out? See code for architecture used.

First I read in the data:

```py
mnist_train = pd.read_csv('data/mnist_train.csv')
mnist_test = pd.read_csv('data/mnist_test.csv')

mnist_train_images = mnist_train.iloc[:, 1:].values
mnist_train_labels = mnist_train.iloc[:, :1].values
mnist_test_images = mnist_test.iloc[:, 1:].values
mnist_test_labels = mnist_test.iloc[:, :1].values

mnist_train_images = mnist_train_images.astype('float32')
mnist_test_images = mnist_test_images.astype('float32')
mnist_train_images /= 255   
mnist_test_images /= 255

mnist_train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(mnist_train_labels, 10)
mnist_test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(mnist_test_labels, 10)

mnist_train_images = mnist_train_images.reshape(60000,28,28,1)
mnist_test_images = mnist_test_images.reshape(10000,28,28,1)
```

Then I build my model and train:

```py
num_classes = mnist_test_labels.shape[1] 

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(mnist_train_images, mnist_train_labels, validation_data=(mnist_test_images, mnist_test_labels), epochs=20, batch_size=256, verbose=2)

scores = model.evaluate(mnist_test_images, mnist_test_labels, verbose=0)

print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))

model.save('mnist-weights.model')
model.save_weights("mnist-model.h5")
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("mnist-model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

But when I then load the model in another application and try to predict probabilities like this, the described error occurs. What am I doing wrong?

```py
json_file = open('alphabet_keras/mnist_model.json', 'r')
model_json = json_file.read()
model = model_from_json(model_json)
model.load_weights("alphabet_keras/mnist_model.h5")

letter = cv2.cvtColor(someImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
letter = fitSquare(letter,28,2) # proprietary function, doesn't matter
letter_expanded = np.expand_dims(letter, axis=0)
letter_expanded = np.expand_dims(letter_expanded, axis=3)
model.predict_proba(letter_expanded)#[0]
```

The output is as follows: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

I expect something like:
array([[0.1, 0.34, 0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 0.62, 0.67, 1.0, 0.31, 0.59]], dtype=float32)

There are not error messages of any kind. Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output is not correct, for classification the output of a neural network is a probability distribution over the labels, which means that the probabilities are between 0 and 1, and that they sum to 1.0. The values you show sum to more than 1.0.

About your specific problem, it looks the probabilities are saturated, this is caused by the fact that you are not normalizing the pixel values by dividing by 255, which you are doing with the training and testing sets, this inconsistency will saturate the output neurons.

Comment: After normalizing my inference data it works, thanks! (I know the expected output I provided is not possible, I just typed in some values between 0 and 1 )